# Backbone Project, How to navigate back when there is a iframe within the view?

Tags: iframe, backbone.js, history

How to navigate back when there is a iframe within the view?

After user clicks on a link to other pages from within the iframe, the browser history gets append on to it as well so that I cant use "window.history.back()" to go back, since "-1" will take user back within iframe and not the actual app itself.

What is a good way to solve this so that when back button pressed its the previous "route" and not the history of iframe history?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Not found any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

try doing something like this, from the Iframe:

```
window.top.history.back();
```

or

```
<a href="javascript: window.top.history.back()">back to backbone app</a>
```

This way you are accessing the Iframe's parent window history, not the Iframe itself. As long as you navigate to the Iframe from your SPA, this should work.